# Is it possible to make two-way communication between two devices via NFC?

Tags: android, callback, nfc, nfc-p2p

I am trying to provide an application which sends multiple data between two different devices via NFC. For ex: device1 sends "date" comment and device2 gets the comment via NFC communication and then device2 checks the comment coming from device1. For device2, "date" means date of today and then device2 sends response message (such as 23.05.2013 14:21:45) at the same time. Not only "date" comment, but also the other comments should be used for the communication. For ex: when device1 sends "who are you" comment via NFC, device2 should send "i am Alice's device" at the same time. Is it possible? Can i make such a communication between two different devices at the same time? Thank you for your help.

Comment: check this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

Sending data via Android Beam in response to a received NDEF message transfered via Android Beam is not possible.

Technically the protocol Android Beam is built upon (LLCP) allows bi-directional data exchange on roughly 240 logical channels at the same time. This capability is just not exposed to Android applications.

You can hope for an API update, but I wouldn't wait for it. A hidden API for this existed in Android 2.3.3 but was later removed for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

As Nils said - via NFC alone, this is not possible due the the limited Android API.

However, I am aware of one way of achieving it by using connection handover. Essentially, the NFC communication is used to send some credentials to the other device that allow the two of them to connect over Bluetooth.

The [EasyNFC](https://github.com/Mobisocial/EasyNFC) library claims to achieve this bluetooth functionality. I gave it a try and I think I was able to set up a socket, but never properly tested it. I didn't find it too reliable and I did not want the addition of bluetooth in my application, nor the use of the "Touch-to-beam" UI.